# Would it be a good idea to use Flamingo SVG Transcoder for high quality SVG images in Codename One?

Tags: codenameone

Looking for ways to include vector graphics in my apps I came across [Flamingo SVG Transcoder](http://ebourg.github.io/flamingo-svg-transcoder/).

Flamingo SVG Transcoder includes an Ant Task for creating Java classes from SVG images. These generated classes include the methods `int getOrigX()`, `int getOrigY()`, `int getOrigWidth()`, `int getOrigHeight()`, and `void paint(Graphics)` which paints the image using shapes generated in code.

The generated code is not fully compatible with Codename One but can be adapted very easily.

As I am not so sure, now my question: Would it be a good idea to use Flamingo SVG Transcoder for high quality SVG images in Codename One?

Comment: FYI to the mod who tagged this as opinion based it is not, it is a question of the appropriateness of a tool to the job at hand and it's feasibility. It doesn't ask for tool comparisons or anything like that. When voting to close positive questions with answers it's considered polite to comment first...

Answer (score 0):

That's actually the exact thought I had which is why I [filed this RFE for 3.7](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/1890) a while back.

I'm not sure what's the right format for transcoding output but that's probably a solvable idea.

Comment: The Flamingo SVG Transcoder Ant Task outputs Java source code which uses `java.awt.Graphics2D`. That would be fine for static images, with the exception that the generated code needs to be modified to use `com.codename1.ui.Graphics`.

Comment: I tested it with my company logo which renders pretty & fast :-)

Comment: Did you test it by porting to Codename One code or do you mean tested the swing code?

Comment: I used the Ant Task to generate a Java class from SVG. Then I manually edited and replaced 'Graphics2D' by 'Graphics' and Color by hex integers in the generated source code. If the source SVG contains grouped elements the generated Java source contains transformations which also are incompatible but can be changed to their Codename One equivalents.

Comment: Interesting, I suggest moving this discussion to the issue tracker on how this can be implemented in a generic way with a proper fork of flamingo. Also of what features we'd need in Codename One to reach feature parity